# Open help file (chm) in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, chm

I'm trying to open help file using VB.NET

```
Help.ShowHelp(helpForm, sFile, HelpNavigator.TableOfContents, "Indice degli argomenti per la stampa")
```

or

```
Help.ShowHelp(helpForm, sFile, HelpNavigator.TableOfContents, 150)
```

but doesn't works.

How can I open this content

[image]

using `Help.ShowHelp` method?

Thanks, Luigi.

Comment: My guess is that you need the  url inside the CHM ,  not the title of that item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is explicitly mentioned in the MSDN Library article for Help.ShowHelp():

> You can use the *param* parameter to provide further refinement of the Topic, TopicId, KeywordIndex, or AssociateIndex command. If the value specified in the command parameter is TableOfContents, Index, or Find, **this value should be an empty string**. If the command parameter references Topic, TopicId, KeywordIndex, or AssociateIndex, this value should be a string that contains the topic name, or the keyword or numeric identifier of the topic to display.

So use Topic or TopicId instead of TableOfContents.

The api isn't otherwise sophisticate enough to let you arrange help viewer windows, if that's what you are really after.  That's up to the user.